# Why does my UITableViewCell have width different from my UITableView's width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

The trouble is this: I have a custom table view cell, that is used by a table view, which in turn is generic. The width of that table view is set to 240 via IB. Assuming that the cell will have the same width as the table, I went on and added some logic as to calculate rects for an image view and two labels, which are subsequently added to the cell's content view. As it turned out, my assumption was wrong.
Trying to discover what is wrong, I went on and overridden tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:. The thing is this method shows that the width of the cell will be the desired 240 points, but it gets called after the designated initialiser of the custom cell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:, which, oddly enough, returns 320 points.

The following is the initialisation of the cell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"cell frame at init: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
        self.avatarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.height, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.avatarView];

        self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.avatarView.frame.size.width + 10, 0, self.frame.size.width - self.avatarView.frame.size.width - 40, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];

        self.visitorsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.avatarView.frame.size.width + self.nameLabel.frame.size.width + 20, 0, self.frame.size.width - (self.avatarView.frame.size.width + self.nameLabel.frame.size.width + 20), self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        self.visitorsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.visitorsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.visitorsLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The information for the subviews is supplied in a different method.
This is the code in the controller, delegate of the table view:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewClubTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell"];
    Club *club = [self.clubs getClubAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [[NewClubTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"newCell"];
    [cell setAvatar:club.avatar name:club.name visitors:club.visitors];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"table view will display frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
}
```

And this is the result from the logs:

```
2014-05-03 16:18:04.143 FanStation[2436:70b] cell frame at init: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.144 FanStation[2436:70b] table view will display frame: {{0, 0}, {240, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.145 FanStation[2436:70b] cell frame at init: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.146 FanStation[2436:70b] table view will display frame: {{0, 44}, {240, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.146 FanStation[2436:70b] cell frame at init: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.147 FanStation[2436:70b] table view will display frame: {{0, 88}, {240, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.147 FanStation[2436:70b] cell frame at init: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.148 FanStation[2436:70b] table view will display frame: {{0, 132}, {240, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.148 FanStation[2436:70b] cell frame at init: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-05-03 16:18:04.149 FanStation[2436:70b] table view will display frame: {{0, 176}, {240, 44}}
```

As you can see, the table view gives correct width, but still the cell has it's own mind about it.

My question is if I'm doing something wrong here, and if there is a way to rectify this issue?
If you would require any additional information on this case, I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A table view cell has no idea what size it should be in it's initializer. It gets initialized at a default size (320 points) and then resized before being displayed. Don't pay attention to the size that's set in the init method.

What you are seeing is perfectly normal.

You'll see the same thing with the main view in view controllers. The view gets created at it's default size and orientation in viewDidLoad, and then sized and rotated for display.

### EDIT:

If you need to be notified when your cells have been resized, you can implement the view controller method didLayoutSubViews. That will get called both when cells are initially size for the table view after initialization, and after the size of the view controller's content view changes (After device rotation, for example.)

Comment: I think you need to mention that UITableView calls layoutSubviews, which cause the resizing of the cell.

Comment: What @Basheer_CAD said.

Comment: I hear what you say. So what you mean is that I need that layoutSubviews to give some proper sizes to the cell's subviews?

Comment: And as you say, layoutSubviews is part of the table view. In that case, at what point am I to safely assume that my cell has its correct sizes, so that it can add subviews with proper dimensions?

Comment: UIViewController has a method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that gets called when the VCs content view has updated it's sup views. You could put your logic there. `viewWillAppear` and` viewDidAppear` are also safe places to assume that the view's layout has been updated. (However `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` won't get called again on a user interface rotation, where `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will get called again

Comment: If you want this logic in your custom table view cell class instead of in the view controller, you could *probably* also override the `layoutSubviews` method for the cell. I say probably because I'm not sure if this would be called for the cell, or only for the cell's content view. I haven't tried it so I can't be sure.

Comment: I cannot up vote, otherwise "You are my saviour, man, my personal Jesus Christ!"

Answer (score 4):

After the very helpful discussion with @Duncan C and @Basheer_CAD I feel the need to elaborate on the solution of the problem I presented with the current post.
I thought it would be foul if I did any UITableViewCell subviews initialisation outside the cell itself. So following the advises of the two mentioned above, I went on and overridden the cell's `layoutSubviews`, where I create the rects for the subviews. As it turns out though, `layoutSubviews` arrives on the scene very late, rendering my method providing the information for the subviews useless. So I had to create additional properties to temporarily store an image and two strings. Which are then used in the process of initialising the subviews.
Again, this is the code in the controller and if you follow the number, you'll get the sequence:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewClubTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell"];
    Club *club = [self.clubs getClubAtIndex:indexPath.row];
(1)
    cell = [[NewClubTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"newCell"];
(3)
    [cell setAvatar:club.avatar name:club.name visitors:club.visitors];

    return cell;
}
```

This is the cell's initialiser. As you can see, it does nothing:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier avatar:(UIImage *)avatar name:(NSString *)name visitors:(NSInteger)visitors
{
(2)
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

The data transfer method:

```
-(void)setAvatar:(UIImage *)avatar name:(NSString *)name visitors:(NSInteger)visitors
{
    (4)
    self.avatarImage = avatar;
    self.name = name;
    self.visitors = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", visitors];
}
```

And finally, `layoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
(5)
    self.avatarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.height, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    self.avatarView.image = self.avatarImage;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.avatarView];

    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.avatarView.frame.size.width, 0, self.frame.size.width - self.avatarView.frame.size.width - 40, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.nameLabel.text = self.name;
    self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];

    self.visitorsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.avatarView.frame.size.width + self.nameLabel.frame.size.width, 0, self.frame.size.width - (self.avatarView.frame.size.width + self.nameLabel.frame.size.width), self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    self.visitorsLabel.text = self.visitors;
    self.visitorsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.visitorsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.visitorsLabel];
}
```

The beauty of it is that only one method in the lifecycle was the key to have the whole thing up and running and properly displaying no matter the device and its orientation.